How to attach replacement shutter bits to stucco
The (decorative) shutter on our house has started to rot. I don't know what I am doing, in general, but moreso in this situation. Can somebody double check my plan:

remove all rotten bits.
stucco patch the wall where it is then left exposed (non yellow part in second picture). (?)
wait for stucco patch to cure.
prime and paint stucco patch.
cut new decorative shutter pieces to match, prime them on 6 sides.
attach the new pieces using construction adhesive. (?)
caulk around new pieces when adhesive is dry.
prime and paint.

I'm particularly unsure about 6 and 2. I have no experience drilling into stucco and am afraid I would only introduce new routes for water. Moreover, the new pieces to add should not be super heavy and have a large amount of shared surface with the wall, so I think adhesive should work. I also don't know if I need to patch this area, but I am concerned that water may be coming in here.
FWIW, this part of the house faces the ocean in the SF bay area; fog and salty air are a constant threat.



Your plan looks solid, but consider vinyl shutters. They will not rot, don't need painted and are mounted with plastic pins that also won't rot or rust. They can be ordered in a variety of colors.
No matter what type of shutter you decide on, before you use the plastic pin or a screw, fill the hole drilled with a polyurethane caulk to prevent water intrusion.
